# Add member(s) to Google Drive Shared Drive with Python

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-colaboratory, drive

How can I add a member to a Google Drive's Shared Drive?

I am working on a Colab and tried to search but nothing useful came up.

I tried using PyDrive but:

- I can't select the whole Shared Drive, only a folder
- I can't update permissions on the folder even tought I can do it through the google drive web gui

This is what I'm doing now (error 400):

```
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
from google.colab import auth
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
from google.colab import drive as drv
drv.mount('/gdrive', force_remount=True)
auth.authenticate_user()
gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)

%cd /gdrive/Shared\ drives/

file_list = drive.ListFile({'q': "  title = 'FolderTitleOrSharedDriveTitle'"}).GetList()
for file1 in file_list:
  print('title: %s, id: %s' % (file1['title'], file1['id']))
  file = file1
print(file['title'])
file.GetPermissions()

new_permission = {
    'type': 'user',
    'value': 'usertogrant@access.com',
    'role': 'reader'
}
permission = file.auth.service.permissions().insert(fileId=file['id'], body=new_permission, supportsAllDrives=True).execute(http=file.http)
```

Comment: arnt shared drives part of gsuite have you tried going though the admin sdk?

Comment: @DaImTo i'm not very experienced with this, I'm not even admin (but I can add memebers), how does it work using the sdk?